# Close all active window and open new one

Tags: c#, wpf

I make some application then i need function for close all active window in c#

but i need to open new one after that

so my code is..

```
 for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
                App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Close();
            Dashboard mf2 = new Dashboard();
            mf2.mastersupplier_clicked(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
            mf2.ShowDialog();
```

but my application is exit and never show the dashboard dialog back.... any idea about this? im stuck in this function,.

i make this with wpf c#

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ShutdownMode` of the `App` to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` before you close the windows:

```
App.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
    App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Close();

Dashboard mf2 = new Dashboard();
mf2.mastersupplier_clicked(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
//shut down the app explicitly when the dashboard dialog is closed:
mf2.Closed += (ss, ee) => App.Current.Shutdown();
mf2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

test this code

```
Dashboard mf2 = new Dashboard();
mf2.mastersupplier_clicked(sender, new RoutedEventArgs());
mf2.Show();
for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
{
   var wnd = App.Current.Windows[intCounter] as Window;
   if(wnd != mf2)
   {
       wnd.Owner = mf2;
       wnd.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: its make double window and the last one not close...

Comment: You do not need to use ShowDialog() when you close all windows and the last one stays. I modified the code and now only the last window is displayed.

Comment: finally im use

 for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
                App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Hide();

so i hide all process then reload a new one,..

Comment: but thanks a lot for , thats help me a lot